# InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException in Spring boot and couchbase when doing findAll()

Tags: java, spring-data, couchbase

I like to get all the documents of a certain type from the Couchbase bucket.

I created a `CatRepository` that extends `CouchbaseRepository`, so I have the `findAll()` method inherited.

When running the program and reaching the line of:

```
Iterable<Cat> all = catRepository.findAll();
```

I get the following error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] 
threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: View  cat/all does not exist.; nested exception is 
com.couchbase.client.java.error.ViewDoesNotExistException: View cat/all does not exist.] with root cause

rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext 
value: com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject.class
at rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(OnErrorThrowable.java:118) ~[rxjava-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:73) ~[rxjava-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:77) ~[rxjava-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
at rx.internal.producers.SingleProducer.request(SingleProducer.java:65) ~[rxjava-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211) ~[rxjava-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102) ~[rxjava-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102) ~[rxjava-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSingle$ParentSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorSingle.java:113) ~[rxjava-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:281) ~[rxjava-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:216) ~[rxjava-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) ~[rxjava-1.2.7.jar:1.2.7]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

And here is the Repository (no) code:

```
public interface CatsRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Cat, String> {
  // nothing here, as the findAll() is inherited
}
```

Comment: Can you post your repository code?

Answer (score 1):

`findAll` requires a view to be created on Couchbase itself.

You can do this through the Couchbase UI:

- Log onto the Couchbase UI
- go to Indexes (left hand menu)
- Views (upper middle)
- select your bucket (top right drop down)
- Add View (top right)
- use a name matching your object (foo), and a view name `all`, so the document is called `_design/[bucket_name]/foo` and view `all`
- (optionally) edit the view, replacing the Map code:

```
    function (doc, meta) {
        if (doc._class == "[your_package].Foo") {
            emit(meta.id, null);
        }
    }
```

- Publish the view (should then appear in the Production Views list)

NB: this answer relates to Couchbase 6. The process might be different on older/newer versions

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the annotation @ViewIndexed as follows:

```
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "area")
public interface AreaRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Area, String> {

     List<Area> findByBusinessUnityIdAndRemoved(String businessId, boolean removed);
}
```